Generate Python Executable using Py2app
I want to create a python executable using py2app for MAC OS, where I am currently working with. Right, my code is this:

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from seleniumbase import Driver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd #pandas se utiliza para poder trabajar con excel


import time

class bcolors:
    HEADER = '\033[95m'
    OKBLUE = '\033[94m'
    OKCYAN = '\033[96m'
    OKGREEN = '\033[92m'
    WARNING = '\033[93m'
    FAIL = '\033[91m'
    ENDC = '\033[0m'
    BOLD = '\033[1m'
    UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'


driver = Driver(uc=True)

pricesIdealo = []

productsToCheck = ["3TS395BDS", "3TS390B", "3TS995XP", "3VS5031IP", "3VS5031BP", "3KFD763XE", "3KFD763WE", "3KFE560WI", "3HB4821X2", "3EB967LU", "3EB765LQ"
                   ,"3EB721LR", "WGG244F1ES", "WUU28T6KES", "SMS2HMW04", "KGN39XIDP", "KGN36VWDA", "HRA574BS0", "HBA5360S0", "PKK631FP8E", "PID61RHB1E"]


try:
    driver.get("https://www.idealo.es/")

    ############## Aceptamos las cookies de manera manual ##############

    time.sleep(2)

    index=0

    df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Aparato', 'Vendedor', 'Precio', 'Fecha'])

    date = datetime.now()
    date = date.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")

    for product in productsToCheck:                 ############## Busqueda de producto ##############
        try:
            element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "i-search-input"))

            )
            input_element = driver.find_element(By.ID, "i-search-input")
            input_element.clear()
            input_element.send_keys(product + Keys.ENTER)

            price = "10000000.0"

            ######## Ordenamos los resultados en orden ascendente

            try:
                element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//option[@value='PRICE_ASC']"))

                )
                input_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//option[@value='PRICE_ASC']").click()

            except:
                print(
                    bcolors.FAIL + "ERROR: No es posible encontrar la opción de ordenacion ascendente. Comprobar el ID del elemento o la conexion a Internet" + bcolors.ENDC)

            try:
                element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='sr-resultList__item']"))

                )
                input_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='sr-resultList__item']")

                try:
                    href = input_element.find_element(By.XPATH,".//a[@href]")
                    href = href.get_attribute("href")
                    driver.get(href)

                    ################### Si se entra en esta seccion implica que hay una lista de valores. Debemos quedarnos solo con los 5 precios mas bajos #############
                    input_element = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[@class='productOffers-listItemOfferPrice']")
                    vendors = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[@class='productOffers-listItemOfferShopV2LogoLink']")

                    c = 0
                    for element in input_element:
                        if(c < 5):
                            price = element.text

                            pos = vendors[c].accessible_name.find('-')
                            vendor = vendors[c].accessible_name[0:pos - 1]

                            df1.loc[index] = [product, vendor, price, date]  ##Imprimimos la fila en el excel
                            index = index + 1
                            c = c + 1

                        else:
                            break

                except:
                    provitionalPrices = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='sr-detailedPriceInfo__price']")
                    vendors = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='sr-singleOffer__shopName sr-singleOffer__shopName--GRID']")
                    c = 0

                    for subprice in provitionalPrices:
                        pos = subprice.text.find('€')
                        printPrice = subprice.text[0:pos+1]

                        pos = vendors[c].text.find('Detalles')
                        pos2 = vendors[c].text.find(':')
                        vendor = vendors[c].text[pos2+1:pos-1]

                        df1.loc[index] = [product, vendor, printPrice, date] ##Imprimimos la fila en el excel
                        index = index + 1
                        c += 1
            except:
                print(
                    bcolors.FAIL + "ERROR: No hay resultado de producto para " + bcolors.BOLD + product + bcolors.ENDC + bcolors.FAIL + ". Asegúrese de que está bien escrito." + bcolors.ENDC)

        except:
            print(
                bcolors.FAIL + "ERROR: No es posible identificar la barra de búsquedas de Idealo. Comprobar el ID del elemento o la conexion a Internet" + bcolors.ENDC)

    df1.to_excel("./Datos/GamaAmigo/GamaAmigo.xlsx", index=False)

except:
    print(bcolors.FAIL + "ERROR: Error al cargar la página. Por favor, revise la dirección URL e inténtelo de nuevo." + bcolors.ENDC)



I have tried it and it works just fine. I have created a setup.py file like this:
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

APP = ['gamaAmigo.py']
DATA_FILES = []
OPTIONS = {}

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    packages=find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True,
    install_requires=[
        'seleniumbase',
        'pandas',
    ],
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)


Then, I execute python setup.py py2app, but I get the following error:
ImportError: No module named PyInstaller.hooks.hook-PySide6.QtUiTools
Everytime I change a thing, I get a different import error. I´m new with this approach so I don´t have an idea of what is happening.
I have tried to install some dependencies but it seems not to change anything.
